# Facebook SDK for iOS issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello I have run though this tutorial, [link](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/532/),  and I have downloaded the source code and run and checked it against my own but I get errors that they don't seem to get.

I believe that it has to do with Facebook updating their SDK since the release of this.

I get something like 6 errors when I try to run the example and all of them say the same thing except for one:

```
Semantic Issue
Method in protocol not implemented
Required for direct or indirect protocol 'FBSessionDelegate'
```

and the other says:

```
Semantic Issue
Incomplete implementation
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The warning is telling you exactly what you need to know.  There is a required method in the FBSessionDelegate protocol that you are not implementing in your delegate.  Review the SDK to see what that method is - and this will go away.  Without your code - there isn't much else we can tell you.